# What happened to the migrate options?

Tags: discussion

You want us to migrate the question to meta so that somebody can evaluate it? There used to be Linux and Stack overflow i think?

Did they get sick and tired of Raspberry Pi questions?

[image]

Comment: ... I'm not sure. We were only allowed a couple because of being in beta. Perhaps they changed the rules.

Answer (score 4):

For now, if you think it belongs on another site just flag it as off-topic and we will deal with migration if applicable.  The tool for migrating to a specific site is currently restricted to moderators.